# QTreeView Border/Frame Color

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

I'm currently working with `QTreeView` and I would like to change widgets's border/frame when control has focus.

I tried already different settings, but as far none of them worked.

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: i guess you have tried stylesheets? Also, it inherits from QFrame, so you should try setting a framewidth that way

Comment: I tried both of these ways...
Maybe placing my QTreeView in QFocusFrame would result in achieving desired behaviuor :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set stylesheet for QTreeView to change the border as per requirement. Some examples are given [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/stylesheet-examples.html). QTreeView has stylesheet properties : **frameShape, frameShadow, border, border-top-color, border-bottom-color**. You can modify these properties to get the desired border style.